# What is the most efficient way to group data in Parse?

Tags: parse-platform, nosql

I'm building an application where users will be matched with each other. I have a university column in PFUser class, and user who might be matched must be from the same university. Users from different universities will never be in an interaction. When I want to return students from the same university, this would solve my problem:

```
query.whereKey("university", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!["university"])
```

However, I feel like this method is extremely inefficient. For example, there might be million users in total, but just 50 students from the particular university. I do not want to check million entities to get these 50 rows.

It would be much faster if I have a particular table for each university with the exact same configuration, but as far as I know, it is also not a correct way of implementing the database.

How should I implement my database or which methods of Parse I should use to have the fastest return time?

Comment: On a very separate note Parse will end its service next year.

Comment: I should have told that I am using open source parse running on Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solutions is coming through adding indexes on the related columns. On the other hand, parse adds indexes based on the incoming query stream.